# In Selenium, find out if webelement is in Window or iframe

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In selenium, when I land on a web page or open a web page, I am using driver.switchTo.activeElement() to find which element(Say element textbox2) on the web page is receiving the focus among say 20 elements(say textbox1, textbox2, radio1, radio2, chkbox1, chkbox2, label1, label2, so on) the moment I land on the page. So we can say that the  default focus is on some element(say textbox2) when I land on the page.

How can I find whether it is in Window or frame programatically ? Ofcourse I can inspect through Firebug and find out whether it is in Window or iframe manually but I don't want to do manual inspection but get it programatically by using some Selenium method or Javascript function.
Do we have something like getXpath() method in Selenium or Javascript to extract the Xpath of the element ? Any other way to know if not through Xpath to know if the element is in Window or iframe(frame) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell whether you are using the root DOM or the frame DOM based on when you switched.

When you start Selenium you will always be under context "root DOM" unless you explicitly call `switchTo.frame()`

Therefore, you can

> find out if webelement is in window or iframe

by your code.

Ask your self:

- Did I use `switchTo.frame()`?

**If so**; your element was in an iframe/frame.

**If not**; your element was in the "Window" (root DOM)

*Footnote*:
It's impossible to return `WebElement`'s from within `<iframe>`s by a `findElement()` invocation **unless** you previously `switchTo.frame()` it.

Comment: I am not using switchTo.frame or switchTo.window(). I am just saying switchTo.activeElement() which  means I open any web page(say yahoo.com, msn.com, amazon.com) and trying to find out which is the first element that is having the focus the moment I land on the page, without switching into a frame. I will come to know the first element which has the auto-focus set by Developer. Now I would like to know whether this element is in frame or window.

Comment: I agree with you since I have not used switchTo.frame(), I should assume that I am in DOM window. But I have a scenario where the page has been developed in such  a way that when I use switchTo.activeElement(), the element being returned is present in "iframe", which I came to know on doing manual inspection through firebug. So the developer can develop a page where the element that receives the first focus can be either in Window or frame(iframe). So how can I know whether the element that receives the auto-focus is in Window or frame

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question is that you want to know if an element is inside an iframe or in a window.

By window you refer to the main window of the browser or an external window opened by a click on a link or something like that?

Maybe you can identify the element identifying the **id** or **tag** or **class** and get the **URI** of the element

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].baseURI;
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("w3-btn w3-white w3-border")[0].baseURI
```

It's important to know that each iframe has a different path from the URL.

The element inside an iframe has the URI of the iframe the one that it's different from the URL.

Now you just compare if the URI is different from the URL then is inside an iframe, and if is not, then is inside the main window.

Comment: By window you refer to the main window of the browser or an external window opened by a click on a link or something like that? Yes I refer to main window of the browser. It's true that I am not using switchTo.frame() initially in my code, I am just using switchTo.activeElement() to find out the element which is receiving the focus the moment I land on the page. In my case Developer has actually set the focus to an element within the frame, which I am able to know automatically on using switchTo.activeElement() without using switchTo.frame().  switchTo.activeElement() can get into frame

Comment: Okay, as I said above, if you want to know if an specific element is inside an iframe you can compare the URL with the base URI that all elements have. And then you know if there's a switchTo needed

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't know itself when to switch to the frame or to the window. In your code, if you have explicitly mentioned `switchTo.frame();` , then only frame DOM will be accessed otherwise by default it's root DOM.